# JavaScript function returning NaN even though value is a number

Tags: javascript, function

I am working on a course assignment where random questions are asked with 4 possible answers each. (This all runs in the console only, working with `alert()`).

My issue is with the score of the user. It is supposed to increment by 1 with each correct iteration and I attempted resolving this using a function, but the function returns `NaN` and I simply can't see the problem. Please have a look.

```
//Start by creating objects to contain the questions and answers
var Questions = function(question, answerq1, answerq2, answerq3, answerq4) {
  this.question = question;
  this.answerq1 = answerq1;
  this.answerq2 = answerq2;
  this.answerq3 = answerq3;
  this.answerq4 = answerq4;
};

//create the questions 
var question1 = new Questions('What is the fastest land animal in the world?', 'a dog', 'deer', 'cheetah', 'leopard');

//create a function that displays the question and present the possible answers as multiple option
function displayQandA() {
  var test = 'question' + 1;
  console.log(test);
  if (test === 'question1') {
    console.log(question1.question);
    var q10a = [question1.answerq1, question1.answerq2, question1.answerq3, question1.answerq4];
    //correct answer in array
    var correct = q10a[2];
    for (var i = 0; i < q10a.length; i++) {
      console.log([i] + ' ' + q10a[i]);
    }
    captureAnswer(q10a.indexOf(correct));
  } else {
    displayQandA();
  }
};
displayQandA();

//to hold score accumulation
var s = 0;
//function to increase score per correct answer        
function incrementScore() {
  s++;
  return s;
};

//function to prompt user to enter/capture the answer & check whether its correct or not
function captureAnswer(el) { //el is the parameter from the random question function
  var promptAnswer = prompt('Capture your answer here');

  if (promptAnswer === 'exit') {
    console.log('You entered ' + promptAnswer);
    console.log('Bye, thanks for playing');
  } else if (promptAnswer == el) {
    console.log('You entered ' + promptAnswer);
    console.log('Your answer is correct!');
    incrementScore();
    console.log('Your score is ' + s);
    displayQandA(); //calling random question function
  } else if (promptAnswer !== el) {
    console.log('You entered ' + promptAnswer);
    console.log('Your answer is wrong!');
    console.log('Your score remains ' + s);
    displayQandA(); //calling random question function
  }
};
```

Comment: I can’t reproduce this. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: None of the functions return anything. Where, precisely, do you see `NaN`? Your code fragment doesn't actually do anything: You define two functions but don't call them in the example. What data are you passing? What value are you typing into the prompt? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: The code above works fine... https://jsfiddle.net/x12azze2/

Comment: I have 'slimmed' the code down as much as possible. If you run it now, you'll clearly see the NaN in console. KEEP IN MIND: the answer is the number "3" and to exit the game, type "exit". I know I know, infinite looping was a requirement of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you call `displayQandA` before assigning `s = 0`. The function already reads `s` (yielding `undefined`) and increments it (yielding `NaN`). `var s;` is hoisted up, so it’ll start as `undefined`. `s = 0;` actually won’t be executed until after you type `"exit"` in the prompt. Simply move `var s = 0;` to the top of your code.

Comment: This resolved my issue. As simple as moving the var declaration to the top. Thanks a MILLION Xufox!!!

Answer (score -1):

Use parseInt() to typecast your variable, the comparison operator (!==) checks for either type or value difference.

Comment: That doesn’t explain why and where there is a `NaN` output.

Answer (score -1):

=+ is not the same as +=. First is x = +y and another is x = x + y.

+x is a shortcut for Number(x) literally converting the variable to number. If the operation can't be performed, NaN is returned.

+= acts like string concatenation when one of the parts (left or right) has a string type.

Comment: `=+` doesn’t appear anywhere in the code. This doesn’t seem to be related to the question at all.